# Deleting a few list items inside of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, del

Deleting a few list items inside of dictionary

Hi,
I have a dictionary:

```
phone = {"first":100,"second":200,"third":[10,12,5,38],"fourth":400}
```

Let' say I want to remove the 12 and 5 from from "phone" dictionary.
Is there a way to do that using a "del" function?

I know how to do this, using a .remove()

```
phone["third"].remove(12)
phone["third"].remove(5)
```

but I was wondering if it is possible to do it using the del()?
Thank you.

EDIT: For all those replies concentrating on "del uses index, remove uses the exact value", I am redefining my question:

I want to delete the indexes 1 and 2 in the list representing the third key-value item in "phone" dictionary. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this by index rather than value:

```
>>> phone = {"first":100,"second":200,"third":[10,12,5,38],"fourth":400}
>>> del(phone["third"][1:3])
>>> phone
{'second': 200, 'fourth': 400, 'third': [10, 38], 'first': 100}
```

This deletes elements in position 1 and 2 in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `del()` or you can re-create the list by filtering it:

```
>>> phone = {"first":100,"second":200,"third":[10,12,5,38],"fourth":400}
>>> phone['third'] = [x for x in phone['third'] if x not in (12,5)]
>>> phone
{'second': 200, 'fourth': 400, 'third': [10, 38], 'first': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access values of the phone dictionary, Remove items of the List .

other answer - try get the item (key, value) containing data you want to change. remove it from dictionary. modify values (list) of this item. and then add it to dictionary

Comment: Hi Amira, is this what you told me:
    editedList = phone["third"]
    del editedList[1:3]

    phone["third"]= editedList

Answer (score 0):

You can treat phone["third"] as a list since that is what it evaluates to.  For instance, if you know the indexes of the items you want to remove you can do:

```
phone["third"][1:3]=[]
```

or

```
del phone["third"][1:3]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you dansalmo.
By the way the "()" around the "del" is a feature of Python 3 or?

Comment: I have Python 2.7 and it worked for me.  Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes, I can. Just from the book from which I am currently learning python (I have no programming background) "del" function is use without the parentheses. And with white space: del b[phone][1:3]
But I see now the effect is the same when using the oarentheses.

Comment: `del` is a statement, not a function, that's why the parenthesis are redundant

Comment: Thank you jamylak.
Btw, why aren't the code block's four whitespaces indentations not working in comments? They worked perfectly well in the starting post.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement del is a way to delete by index not value, however you can search the index first if you want. Better to use remove if you want to delete by value.

To delete the element at index 1 and 2

```
>>> phone = {"first":100,"second":200,"third":[10,12,5,38],"fourth":400}
>>> del phone["third"][1]
>>> del phone["third"][2]
>>> phone
{'second': 200, 'fourth': 400, 'third': [10, 5], 'first': 100}
```

Comment: Ok, let's reformulate my question:
I want to delete the indexes 1 and 2 in the list representing the third key-value item in "phone" dictionary.
How can I do that?

Comment: @stgeorge I've added that to my answer